AWS WAF with ALB: In Geo matching rule how to exclude internal IP's
their is an ALB associated with WAF. This ALB will be called by both public and other internal IPs.
I have enabled GEO Matching rule to allow only ["US"] calls. but the internal private IP don't get labelled with any country. and it is getting blocked.
how to exclude internal IPs.

Let me update how I have solved it.
please note the AWS Console UI doesn't support nested conditions. So I have created a rule as below.
requirement: Internal IP's wont have geo locations, So allow Internal IP only or allow external IP only from "US" geo location.
Rule:
{
  "Name": "Allow_Geo_Match_or_Internal_IP",
  "Priority": 2,
  "Statement": {
    "NotStatement": {
      "Statement": {
        "OrStatement": {
          "Statements": [
            {
              "IPSetReferenceStatement": {
                "ARN": "<<IP-SET-ARN>>"
              }
            },
            {
              "GeoMatchStatement": {
                "CountryCodes": ["US"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Action": {
    "Block": {}
  }
}


You could create an IP set for your internal IP addresses and create a rule to allow it:

AWS WAF > IP sets
Click button Create IP set in the upper right corner
IP set name: Allowed internal IPs
Region - choose the region of your WAF
IP addresses - add CIDR range for your internal IP range (for
example 10.0.0.0/16). If you need more ranges or addresses, just
separate them by new line
In your Web ACL > Add rule > Add my own rule
If a request matches a statement > Inspect -> Originates from an IP address in -> IP set - select previously created IP set
Action -> Allow
Save
On next window you will be able to set a priority for rules. Put your new rule on priority that's before the one that's checking countries

